# How can a compiling language be interpreting language

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, interpreter

I have a question.
I actually know the difference between compiling and interpreting languages. 
But, What I do not really understand is , how can any programming language be both compiling and interpreting ? 
Thank you.

Comment: It can be that the language follows different phases(talking about Java here specifically) : it  is both a interpreting language, and also a compiling language. javac compiles source code into java byte code; and the JIT compiler compiles the bytecodes of that method into native machine code.[Check this answer for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14708631/3482140)

Comment: A programming language is neither compiling nor interpreting. Only an implementation is, and one language can have multiple different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If an interpreting language is one for which an interpreter exists and a compiling language is one for which a compiler exists, then a language can be both if someone wrote an interpreter for it and someone else (or the same person/team) wrote a compiler for it.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to "interpret" a program fragment is to compile it and then invoke the compiled code. Using this procedure would allow you to implement any behavioural aspect of an interpreter, such as a REPL, or the `eval` function itself.